# Is tail recursion when a recursive procedure describes an iterative process?

Tags: recursion, iteration, tail-recursion

Is tail recursion when a recursive procedure describes an iterative process? If not could you tell me where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For it to be iterative it needs to only consist of tail calls or some other looping construct like tail calls.

Answer (score 0):

Tail recursive function is one in which the recursive call is the last executed line of the code in the function.